# Javascript not working in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello guys i am trying to embed javascript to the php file navigator user agent but i am facing this error :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/public_html/domain.com/modules/mod_news_pro_gk4/tmpl/layout.parts.php on line 874

here is the code

```
echo '<script  type="text/javascript">
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){

document.write('<?php return ($news_price != '') ? '<div class="nspVmStore">'.$news_price.'<span class="extxt">.00 / Only</span></div> ' : ''; ?>') ;

}

else
document.write("<?php return ($news_price != '') ? '<div class="nspVmStore">'.$news_price.'<span class="extxt">.00 / Only</span></div> ' : ''; ?>");
</script>';
```

Comment: `<?php ?>` inside `echo` string will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$val_1 = ($news_price != '') ? '<div class="nspVmStore">'.$news_price.'<span class="extxt">.00 / Only</span></div> ' : '';
$val_2 = "value 2 here";
?>
<script  type="text/javascript">
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
    document.write("<?php echo $val_1;  ?>");
else
    document.write("<?php echo $val_2;  ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: @ Salim cant we use return instead of echo ?

Comment: We are sending an argument into document.write() method. so return statement should not a part of argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an echo with a php tag inside. Why yo do not create all the output first in a string and then do the echo?

Answer (score 0):

You have parse errros there.. Try it like this:

```
echo '
<script  type="text/javascript">
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        document.write("' . ($news_price != '' ? '<div class=\"nspVmStore\">' . $news_price  . '<span class=\"extxt\">.00 / Only</span></div> ' : '') . '");
    } else {
        document.write("' . ($news_price != '' ? '<div class=\"nspVmStore\">'  . $news_price . '<span class=\"extxt\">.00 / Only</span></div> ' : '') . '");
    }
</script>';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in

Answer (score 0):

Your code like confusing, I guessed you need to change this code

```
document.write("<?php return ($news_price != '') ? "<div class=\"nspVmStore\">".$news_price."<span class=\"extxt\">.00 / Only</span></div>" : ''; ?>") ;
```

Look at semicolon

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$news_price = 1;

?>
<script  type="text/javascript">

if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){

document.write('<?=($news_price != '' ? '<div class="nspVmStore">'.$news_price.'<span class="extxt">.00 / Only</span></div> ' : ''); ?>') ;

} else {
document.write('<?=($news_price != '' ? '<div class="nspVmStore">'.$news_price.'<span class="extxt">.00 / Only</span></div> ' : ''); ?>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working code:

```
echo '<script  type="text/javascript">
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    document.write("'.($news_price != '' ? '<div class="nspVmStore">'.$news_price.'<span class="extxt">.00 / Only</span></div> ' : '') .'") ;
} else {
    document.write("'.($news_price != '' ? '<div class="nspVmStore">'.$news_price.'<span class="extxt">.00 / Only</span></div> ' : '').'");
}
</script>';
```